# Python URI Request for File Protocol in a Shared Folder (not local)

Tags: python-3.x, file, python-requests, urllib

I've been trying to read a file that is under a URI following the `file://` protocol since is in a shared folder, not in local like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123929/fetch-a-file-from-a-local-url-with-python-requests) post, the `open` function does not work.

The file is reachable with my user locally by using the following code.

```
uri = "//128.0.0.1/hello_world.txt"
with open(uri, 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    print(contents)
```

I want to automate that and I've created a Distributed user that can access the shared folder over a Proxy. I don't think the `open` method can be executed by another user like the problem targeted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675464/run-program-as-different-user-on-windows-not-admin-within-a-python-script) neither can add a Proxy in their Configuration.

I've tried other libraries but I couldn't find any that can handle the `file://` protocol. For example, for requests library:

```
import requests

uri = "//128.0.0.1/hello_world.txt"
PATH = f"http:{uri}"
proxies = {"http": f'http://{proxy_user}:{proxy_password}@proxy.com:1234',
           "https": f'https://{proxy_user}:{proxy_password}@proxy.com:1234'
           }
           
x = requests.get(PATH, proxies=proxies)
print(x.status_code)
```

Or this one using `urllib`:

```
from urllib import request

uri = "//128.0.0.1/hello_world.txt"
PATH = f"file:{uri}"
proxies = {"http": f'http://{proxy_user}:{proxy_password}@proxy.com:1234',
           "https": f'https://{proxy_user}:{proxy_password}@proxy.com:1234'
           }

opener = request.FancyURLopener(proxies)
with opener.open(PATH) as f:
    print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

I have tried `samba` as well in order to read from there.

Did anyone find a library that can handle `file://` protocol properly?

Thank you in advance.